# Use string as access token Facebook Android POST request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Im developing an android application.
I have a facebook fan page in which everyone can post through my android application with his own access token.
However , lot of my users would like to post anonymously so what i;m thinking about is to store an access token of a facebook user-account i've created for this purpose , so i will use his accesstoken for all the people who would like anonymous.
However , the new GraphRequest function , can't take as input a string , but only an AccessToken variable.
I have the string of the user's access token , however how am i going to convert it as AccessToken type , so i will pass it in the function?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer this [Facebook AccessToken](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/). Using this you can create **object** of **AccessToken** class using **string access token**

Comment: @Haridarshan thanks for your reply! I just saw this method which needs these parameters :
(String accessToken,String applicationId, String userId, Collection permissions, Collection declinedPermissions, AccessTokenSource accessTokenSource, Date expirationTime, Date lastRefreshTime)
accessToken : ok
applicationid : ok
userId : ok
Collection is a type of arraylist I guess ? I only need publish_actions permission
There are 2 collections.one with permissions , and one with the declined permissions.What do i pass in the 2nd?
Furthermore , i don't have idea what to fill in for the 3 last args

Comment: In case of **declined permission collection** you can pass `null` if you're not sure and about third last argument, you need to pass either one of these values `AccessTokenSource.FACEBOOK_APPLICATION` or `AccessTokenSource.WEB_VIEW`.

Comment: You are not allowed to set up fake user accounts for such a purpose (or any other). Facebook is _not_ a platform to be used “anonymously” - if users want that, they should be looking for a different platform.

Comment: @Haridarshan hello my friend! I don't know what im doing wrong , can u help me? I created Accesstoken variable with the required constructor , however the app crashes everytime.
I think the mistake is made by me in the arguments/parameters of the constructor.
1st : user access token as string OK
2nd: application id as string OK
3rd:Collection with the permissions i need OK
4th: null for the denied permissions
5th: null
6th:null

AccessToken mytoken = new AccessToken(usertoken,myappId,mineId,mypermissions,null,AccessTokenSource.WEB_VIEW,null,null);